# Compilador en Cobol

Tags: ide

****Buen día comunidad, estoy en busca de un IDE para el lenguaje en COBOL,
 que no sea online y de preferencia que sea libre, espero que conozcan alguno.
Estaba usando el compilador "SPFLite Editor", pero necesito algún otro donde pueda ejecutar mis programas, espero conozcan alguno.
Saludos !****

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar OpenCobol IDE, es de software libre y crea ejecutables.
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/OpenCobolIDE
Yo lo utilizo y es muy practico en identación.
Si lo instalas en linux necesitaras tener python instalado entre otros componentes.
Cualquier duda en la instalacion en linux aqui estoy.

Espero que te ayude.

Comment: mi amigo. disculpa . podría hacer unas consultas de cobol?

Answer (score 0):

Si usas Linux puedes usar OpenCobol https://open-cobol.sourceforge.io/ Si usas Windows deberás instarla Cygwin para instalarlo. También existe TinyCOBOL (http://tiny-cobol.sourceforge.net/).